# UIRefreshControl - beginRefreshing not working empty tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like show refreshing spinner when data is loading..

beginRefreshing is not working for the first time. but when the data is loaded. and I refresh. the beginRefreshing works properly.

so How to solve that problem I have tried this :

```
self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0,y: self.tableView.contentOffset.y-self.refreshControl.frame.size.height), animated: true)
```

my swift version: 3